# How to get an ad hoc translation with Zend_Translate

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

I'm using Zend_Translated to translated all my strings

```
$translator->_('hello')
```

If my locale is in french this code will print "`Bonjour`".

When browsing the french version of the site i'd like to output some german text.

```
$translator->_('hello', array(locale=>'en'))
```

This will still output "`Bonjour`" but i'd like "`Guten Tag`"

How can I get a translation of a string in another language than the current locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to output some german text you should use

```
$translator->setLocale('de');
$translator->_('hello');
```

or

```
$translator->_('hello', 'de');
```

ie. either set the locale before translating or specify the locale string as 2nd parameter.

Refer to [Handling languages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.additional.html#zend.translate.additional.languages) for more information.